# React Native: Animation not starting on Android only

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a typical React Native animation like:

```
Animated.timing(this.value, { toValue }).start()
```

and it works fine on iOS, but doesn't work on Android. When I add a callback to the start method, it gets called on iOS, but not on Android.

Answer (score 1):

What's your RN Version? There's a known issue on React Native about animation on Android: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6278

A workaround mentioned is to set your value to `0`, something like this: `this.animation = new Animated.Value(0.01);`

Hope it helps